# Convert hexadecimal code to text in Java

Tags: java

How can I convert code with hexadecimal values to text?

I have this code in java...

```
for (int i = 0; i < hexValue.length(); i += 2)
{
    String str = hexValue.substring(i, i + 2);
    output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
}
```

Can you help me, please? :D

Comment: my string is "0x7B5C727466315C616E73695C64656666305C6465667461623235347B5C666F6E7474626C7B5C66305C73776973735C" and NetBeans give me this error when i run the project.... "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x""

Comment: Get rid of the 0x in front of the String (or skip over it).

Comment: How i ignore that because i need to catch from database? :D

Comment: Simply do: `str.substring(2)`

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast the `int` to `char` before appending it to I'm assuming the `StringBuilder output`? By the way use `String.substring` to remove the `0x` before parsing the int.

Comment: Can you show me that, please?

Comment: Even easier than that it would be to just replace the *int i = 0* by *int i = 2*, so that you will be skipping the two first characters

Comment: Hello Guys. Now I need to put this data in database my sql? Someone can help me? :D